# How to highlight and label a specified point in wpf dynamic data display?

Tags: wpf, charts, points, dynamic-data-display

Do you know how to highlight a specified point in a graph?
Is it also possible to show a label for this specified point?

Any ideas?

Comment: I also need this so much :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create a marker to display at the certain point you would like to accentuate!
First, instantiate any type of an ElementPointMarker.
You can perhaps set a tooltip(for your label?) like :

```
elementPointMarker.ToolTip = "I am a label!";
```

Set up the rest of it and add it to your graph with:

```
plotter.Children.Add(elementPointMarker);
```

If you want to add an actual label instead of a tooltip, you could examine two things.

1. Creating a new marker class that contains text to display on the graph.
2. Examine how the D3 Canvas works and insert a label at a specified point on the canvas.